# VIM to Aptana: indent three lines, or entire block

Tags: aptana

Suppose one has the following code open in Aptana Studio 3:

```
function doSomething()
{
foo();
bar();
baz();
}
```

With the cursor on the `foo();` line, how might I indent the line and the two following it? In VIM this is `3>>`. For that matter, how does one auto-indent the entire block? In VIM this is `=%`.

Note that Aptana has [a link to Stack Overflow when clicking "Browse Discussions"](http://www.aptana.com/support) on their Support website.

Comment: Why not close Aptana and open the file in vim?

Comment: Seems too easy... have you tried tab? You can indent the whole block by selecting it and hitting tab also...

Comment: @SarahKemp: Tab will only indent the current or highlighted lines. Is the only way to highlight a group or count of lines to highlight them first?

Comment: Ohhh, looking to auto indent several lines / whole file. Have you tried `Ctrl + Shift + F`? Also found by right clicking inside of a file and choosing `Source > Format`

Comment: @Sarah: Thanks, that will auto-indent all the code in the file. That solves half of my frustration! But sometimes I have multiple code types in the same file, such as SQL statements in PHP, where I prefer to change the indentation. I see no way to do this in bulk.

Comment: @Sarah: The auto-format did more than just change indentation! I ruined all kinds of formatting throughout the file! It seems that all sorts of formatting need to be set, but I have different clients who have different formatting preferences. I'm not going to change all those settings each time I work on a different client's file just to auto-indent.

Comment: I'm sorry (I hope you were able to undo anything that got messed up?!), the example you gave looked like straight PHP, so that was what I tested on. I don't know about using different formatting for an SQL statement in PHP files, but you can change the formatting rules for a given editor in `Window > Preferences> Aptana Studio > Formatter`. This also includes an option for a `formatteroff` tag you could surround SQL with.